# error Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

I have the function that I detail and it gives me the following error

> Uncaught Reference Error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

```
function obtenerValorPorColorSemaforo(sumCumplimiento, valueColorVerde, valueColorAmarillo) {
         var result = null;
         var porColorVerde = parseFloat(valueColorVerde); // Porcentaje Color Verde
         var porColorAmarillo = parseFloat(valueColorAmarillo); // Porcentaje Color Amarillo.

         if (parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) = 0.00) {
           // Color gris
           result = "panel-defaluft";
         }

         else if (parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) >= porColorVerde) {
           // Color VERDE
           result = "panel-success";
         }

        else if(parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) < porColorVerde &&
                parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) >= porColorAmarillo) {
           // Color AMARILLO
           result = "panel-warning";
         }

         else  {
           // Color ROJO
           result = "panel-danger";
         }

         return result;

       }
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison. You did `if (parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) = 0.00) {`

Comment: `parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) = 0.00` to `parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) == 0.00`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem :

```
 if (parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) = 0.00) {
       // Color gris
       result = "panel-defaluft";
     }
```

it should be :

```
    if (parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) == 0.00) {
       // Color gris
       result = "panel-defaluft";
     }
```

Comment: Yes, I explained this in a comment. No need to answer it. Instead flag it as off-topic due to a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing assingment inside the if

```
 if (parseFloat(sumCumplimiento) = 0.00) {
   // Color gris
   result = "panel-defaluft";
 }
```

Probably you are missing the extra `==`

Comment: Yes, I explained this in a comment. No need to answer it. Instead flag it as off-topic due to a typo.